# How to determine tabId in content script in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm looking for a way to determine the tabId in the content script, so I can send messages from content to popup.

Now, I might be wrong here, but I get the impression it cannot be done. The best solution I've seen so far is this

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("sent from tab.id=", sender.tab.id);
});
```

But in my case no messages are send, so how can the content script send the first message. As far as I know, for the content script to send messages to the popup window the tab-id is needed.

What I'm trying to do here is that the content script sends a message to the popup window when the page is loaded and ready

Comment: Assuming the popup is an html page declared in manifest.json, it runs only when shown so if it's not shown, your message will be lost. Note that you don't need a tab id to send such a message: simply use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and it will be received by all running extension scripts (not content scripts) that have an onMessage listener. Maybe you should describe the workflow you want to achieve, for which a better solution may exist.

Comment: True, it will be lost if there is no popup. But in that case it doesn't matter much. I could do what you suggest and just send a message without tabId. Then the popup can send a message back, in which case the content script will receive the tabId and can resend the message with the tabId.

Comment: My point was that there's no need for tabId in order to send a message to the popup.

Comment: Of think it is important. What if there are multiple popups? (In my case you can have a popup per tab, which I haven't mentioned yet :) ). In that case, you don't want to send the message to the wrong popup

Comment: The popup will simply compare sender.tab.id to the active tab's id.

Comment: Ah, I see, I completely missed that, thats indeed the solution I need, thnx!!